# Why is the date time different for PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date

When I insert an entry into MYSQL the 'datetime' in my MYSQL entry is different from that registered with PHP.  How can I make them register the same date and time?  I am in the UK and I use the Godaddy server.

I have used the following to set the default time:

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

 // TO GET THE PRESENT DATE TIME
 $dateTimeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

For example I made an entry to to my database and I had the following differences in time:

```
 DateTime now (PHP): 2016-09-23 16:40:54
 DateTime of post (from MYSQL): 2016-09-23 08:06:52

 // FOR DATETIME INSERTION INTO MYSQL I USE
 now()
```

Comment: Different you say?

Comment: Can you show us the differences that you are getting please

Comment: Where is the server running your MYSQ Server situated timezone wise

Comment: Yea, show us the code that stores this date to your table

Comment: please see above edit. I use 'now()' in sql to register the DATETIME

Comment: `INSERT (to_date) values (NOW())` will use the servers timezone. Your `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");` is having no effect on this query at all

Comment: I am in the UK, and I use the Godaddy server.

Comment: Then I guess the server is somewhere like USA West Coast

Comment: You need to set the timezone of mysql after connecting to it from php. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/930900/80836